# Move first child of a DOM element to last position without creating garbage nodes

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to put the first span element at the bottom so that is goes from this...

```html
<div id="items">
<span>1</span>
<span>2</span>
<span>3</span>
</div>
```

...to this:

```html
<div id="items">
<span>2</span>
<span>3</span>
<span>1</span>
</div>
```

I've tried using the method below to achieve this, but it seems like it creates garbage DOM nodes in the process when looking at the performance monitor in Chrome DevTools.

```js
const itemsEl = document.getElementById('items');
itemsEl.append(itemsEl.children[0]);
```

Is it possible to do this without creating garbage DOM nodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Try `appendChild`

You might try `appendChild` instead of `append`, since the former has [a narrower job](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) (only accepts one child, child must be a Node), and so DOM impls might do less stage-setting interally to make it work. [The spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-node-appendchild) is just one step.

That said, I think you should consider that this "garbage node" situation is specific to Chrome, and not something you can or should plan around. Today, WebKit creates a garbage node. Next year it might not. [The spec for `append`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-parentnode-append) is just two steps, after all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After some research, it seems like there's no simple way to avoid the DOM garbage. Anyway, I found [this benchmark](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/9176/0/js-append-vs-appendchild) comparing append and appendChild. Seems like appendChild is generally faster looking at the previous test cases.